# Request to external api to get authentication token in google appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am trying to make a call to external api using google Appscript. But i am 
  gettting always error 500.It would be grateful if anyone can help.

> Request failed for https://demo.overconline.com/api/authenticate returned code 500. Truncated server response: {"message":"error.internalServerError","description":"Internal server error","fieldErrors":null} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 10, file "Code")

```
  function getToken(){
  var params ={
    "username": "xxxx",
    "rememberMe": true,
    "password": "xxx",
  };  

  var headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','method':'post','payload':'params'};
  var url = 'https://demo.overconline.com/api/authenticate';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);
  var result = Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText());
  var token = result.access_token;
  Logger.log(result);
```

Comment: When ``headers`` is used as ``UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers)``, ``'Content-Type':'application/json'`` can be modified as ``'contentType':'application/json'``. ``params`` is not used to ``payload`` as an object, because ``'params'`` is enclosed by the single quotes. From the content type, ``payload`` might be ``JSON.stringify(params)``. Reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params). If these modifications were not your solution, can you provide a document for the specification of the API you want to use?

Comment: Then, ``Utilities.jsonParse(jsonString)`` had already been deprecated . So please use ``JSON.parse(jsonString)``.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is worked now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Can you post an answer with your solution? When you posted an answer, please accept it. By this, other users can see the solution for your issue.

Comment: yes i will do it for sure

Comment: Thank you for your response. I confirmed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code for above code.I got the authentication token by this code.

```
function getToken(){
  var params ={
    'username': 'xxxxx',
    'rememberMe': true,
    'password':'xxxxx'
  };  
  var headers = {'contentType':'application/json','method':'post','payload':JSON.stringify(params)};
  var url = 'https://demo.overconline.com/api/authenticate';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
}
```