# I want to get the Time Sheet addon (for Jira ) worklog (per REST API) into a google timesheet but i keep getting "401 Authorization Required"

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used the following code to get the authentication done, but i always get the 401 Error

```
 function authenticateSF(){
  var url = 'request url';
  var options = {
    grant_type:'password',
    client_id:'MyClientId',
    client_secret:'myClientSecret',
    username:'myname@company.de',
    password:'mystrongpassword331'
  };
  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

***Can someone help me with this problem or has an Idea ?***

Comment: Is this request made to Jira directly for the worklog?

Comment: The request is made in the Google sheet script editor and it is directly for the worklog..

Comment: I see, how are you running the script? directly from the editor?

Comment: Yes I run it directly from the Editor.

Comment: Try changing the key for the `option` to strings, as they are in [the method's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)), if that does not help, it might be an issue directly with the Jira API

Comment: I'am not using the Jira Rest API, but the Tempo Sheet Rest API. And I just have to know how I get a Bearer Authentication done in the Google Script Editor to solve my problem. :)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702190) deals with a similar situation, you should take a look. Alternatively, [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis#fetching_data_with_urlfetchapp) is the documentation on working with 3rd party APIs with Google Apps Scripts